# Does a subclass require a constructor/initializer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Usually when I see a subclass, it calls the superclass in the constructor like below:

```
class Boss(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attitude, behaviour, face):
        self.name = name
        self.attitude = attitude
        self.behaviour = behaviour
        self.face = face

    def get_attitude(self):
        return self.attitude

    def get_behaviour(self):
        return self.behaviour

    def get_face(self):
        return self.face

class GoodBoss(Boss):
    def __init__(self, name, attitude, behaviour, face):
        super().__init__(name, attitude, behaviour, face)
```

However on a [website](https://www.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/) I saw an example of a subclass:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 5

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

In the last example why doesn't the Child subclass include `super().__init__()`?

Comment: Parent's constructor doesn't need any parameters, so default implementation for the child works. This works pretty well for e.g. custom exceptions where you just do `pass` in the body like above.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/pass-python
I hope it is helpful.

Comment: `As you can see the Child class is empty, but since it inherits from Parent Python takes charge of routing all method calls. So you may use the get_value() method of Child objects and everything works as expected.`

Comment: Question for others: is there actually any difference between these two cases? Since all `GoodBoss.__init__()` is doing is calling the parent `__init__()` with the same arguments, isn't it identical to not defining `GoodBoss.__init__` at all?

Comment: Hi @AK47 although it inherits from the Parent, don't we do super().__init__() so that it can access the `self.value=5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand this simple code:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Parent is called!')


class ChildA(Parent):
    pass 


class ChildB(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print('ChildB is called!')


class ChildC(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print('ChildC is called!')
        super().__init__()


p = Parent()
print()
ca = ChildA()
print()
cb = ChildB()
print()
cc = ChildC()
print()


print(ChildA.mro())
print(ChildB.mro())
print(ChildC.mro())
```

Output:

```
Parent is called!

Parent is called!

ChildB is called!

ChildC is called!
Parent is called!

[<class '__main__.ChildA'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>]
[<class '__main__.ChildB'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>]
[<class '__main__.ChildC'>, <class '__main__.Parent'>, <class 'object'>]
```

---

**Key Observations:**

1. If a class does not have an implementation of the `__init__()` method, then its parent's `__init__()` will be called *if* it exists.
2. If a class has an implementation of the `__init__()` method, then it will be called. However its parent's `__init__()` will *not* be called automatically.
3. If a class has an implementation of the `__init__()` method, then it will be called. We can call its parent's `__init__()` method by explicitly calling it with `super().method(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hi @Dipen but in my case don't we do `super().__init__()` so that it can access the `self.value=5`?

Comment: Ah I think I understand your observations. So basically since `Child` doesn't have an explicit `init` of itself, then by default it takes the `init` of the Parent.

Comment: Exactly! Play around it.

Answer (score 1):

Classes don't strictly require `__init__()` methods at all.  You can have a class consisted with only class/static attributes/methods and it'll be just as valid, though its usefulness remains to be debated.

The reason you see most classes have `__init__()` method is because most of the time when a class is instantiated you'd want to initialize the class with some values/handling.  If your `Child` class is not doing anything different than the `Parent`'s `__init__()` method, there's no need to redefine `__init__()`.

If the `Child` class needs to redefine `__init__` but still wants to rely on the `Parent`'s `__init__` method, then that's when you need `super().__init__()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, Subclass is calling the **init** method of your parent class in the constructor method. This approach is basically used when we need to set some attributes of subclass method but after/before calling the superclass method. Let's consider below example with setting the **age** attribute in subclass:

```
class Boss(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attitude, behaviour, face):
        self.name = name
        self.attitude = attitude
        self.behaviour = behaviour
        self.face = face

    def get_attitude(self):
        return self.attitude

    def get_behaviour(self):
        return self.behaviour

    def get_face(self):
        return self.face

class GoodBoss(Boss):
    def __init__(self,
            name,
            attitude,
            behaviour,
            face, age):
        super().__init__(name, attitude, behaviour, face)
        self.age = age # here age is an attribute of only GoodBoss class, Not Superclass
```

Here your subclass is setting the age attribute which isn't an attribute of your parent class.This pattern is used when your subclass is doing something different from superclass in constructor function.

In second example, we are not setting/calling any method in constructor function of child class. When we make the object of child class, the parent class **init** function would be called.Your subclass is not doing any different.

These are completely depend on the code design.